# Why the editing area or the main activity of Android studio where we design our UI can't be seen?

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm a newbie to Android studio and is going to start with my first project.

As per a tutorial, I created an empty activity project. But when my project screen opens, I can neither see any main file that is created after making a new project nor I can see the editing area where buttons, text, etc are dragged to make the UI.

I can only see a black screen on the right side with some tips and 2 folders on the left side - Gradle files and project.

So where's the problem? And how to fix it. I searched this question on many sites but was unable to find an easy and understandable answer. Pls if anyone can answer, I'll be obliged...

**EDIT**
As this was my first question on SO, the question was poorly stated and formatted. Apologies for that...

Although, I have solved what the problem was (*was a silly first-time thing*), I am attaching a screenshot of the problem(it's not the exact same as what I was encountering 2 years ago but similar to it) [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U9hR3.png).

One needs to wait for all the Gradle background tasks to finish and needs to expand the app folder to see *java classes or layout files, drawable etc..*

Comment: Please read [ask]

Comment: Can you include screenshots to your question?

Comment: I have edited my answer (after 2 years ). Apologies for my poor language and formatting.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the docs on how to make a new project and the project folders hierarchy 
here https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/creating-project

Mainly after you create a new project and open it, you will get two main folder `app` and `Gradle scripts`, so in order to access your project packages you only need to expand the `app folder` then you will find the manifest file, java folder where you will find your project activities, and a `res` folder, here you will find your main ressources folders like `drawable`, `layout` and `values`.

In order to change and add UI elements you need to access the `layout` folder and that's what you are asking for.

So to resume, to access the java code

```
app > java > com.example.myfirstapp > MainActivity
```

To change and create your UI

```
app > res > layout > activity_main.xml
```

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)